# how to get term vectors by using Elasticsearch Hadoop

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, apache-spark, elasticsearch-hadoop

I'm using ElasticSearch-Hadoop API. And I was trying to get `_mtermvector` by using the following Spark code:

```
val query= """_mtermvectors {
        "ids" : ["1256"],
        "parameters": {
            "fields": [
                 "tname"
            ],
            "term_statistics": true
        }
}"""
var idRdd = sparkContext.esRDD("uindex/type1",query)
```

It didn't work, any ideas please, appreciate!

Comment: Could you share some more info? Does a simple query like: "{"query": { "match_all": {}}}" work?

Comment: But I don't know where should I put _mtermvectors, if you wanna get term vectors you have to use the handler _mtermvectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use endpoints (like _mtermvectors) which are part of the [document API's](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-multi-termvectors.html) with ES-Hadoop. Only queries which belongs to the [query API's](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/search-uri-request.html), [query DSL](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/query-dsl.html) or [external resource](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/configuration.html) are allowed.

Hope that it helps.